# Enhanced For Loop not adding up elements in array

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to add up the elements in the array with an enhanced 
for loop. If I do it with a normal for loop, it works. But when I'm 
using an enhanced for loop it throws an IndexOutOfBounds exception 
and I'm not sure why that's happening?

```
int[ ] array = {1,2,3};
int total = 0; 
for(int counter : array) {
    total = total + array[counter];
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: `total = total + counter`; you would only use `array[i]` if using a `for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) style of loop

Comment: that worked,Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`counter` is not index, its the element. You need to add the `counter` to `total`.

If you are using Java 8 then you can simplify it to:

```
int[ ] array = {1,2,3};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).sum());
```

If you would still like to do it without streams:

```
int[ ] array = {1,2,3};
int total = 0; 
for(int counter : array) {
    total = total + counter;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 3):

As Aniket previoysly said, counter is not an index.

Your code is a shorter version of this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<array.size; i++){
     counter = array[i];
     total = total + counter;
 }
```

As you can see, counter becomes the element of array[i] and i is the index of the array.

If you wanted to keep track of the index using your version of the code, you would have to create an outside variable called i = 0 and increment it by one each repetition.

```
 int i = 0
 for (counter : array){
     i++;
     counter = array[i];
     total = total + counter;
 }
```